# Fix Corrupted NTFS Partition from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I try to fix my Windows(NTFS) Drive from Ubuntu.
 [image: Partitions From Gparted]

The error messages I got from GParted and other software was 
`Input/Output Error during read on /dev/sda`.
Or `Failed to read SYSTEM.SAV`

Another strange thing was that `smrtmontools` said that it passed the health test!

So I tried to fix it with `ntfsfix` but partition `sda2` and `sda3` had the command output:

```
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Now I'm stuck and I don't know how to run this command from Ubuntu.

Comment: No, I couldn't use ntfsfix. It askes me to use chkdsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chkdsk` is a Windows command. You should boot from a Windows installation medium (DVD or USB) and run Windows repair. Make sure that your Windows drive is seen as first drive in BIOS or Windows repair will not be successful (had this issue once and documented it at the end of the following article https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/778/install-linux-mint-18.3-software-raid-mdraid-device-partition).

Comment: I have done it. Waiting for results now. I hope it works because ntfsfix said that some sectors are corrupted

Comment: It worked with chkdsk. Thanks